# Keep vim syntax file in same directory as documents

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim

I am keeping notes in console vim on my laptop, and
I want to add syntax highlighting to my notes in order
to enhance them. However, I don't want to add a
million different filetypes for every area of knowledge
(for example my notes on compilers would have different
keywords than my notes on the FHS), and I also want to
make it easy to share these notes. After doing some
research, I discovered that I can get the behavior I
want, but it doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.
I added the following lines to my `.vimrc`:

```
if (filereadable("./.custom_syntax.vim")
  let mysyntaxfile = "./.custom_syntax.vim"
  syntax enable
else
  syntax enable
endif
```

I don't really like this solution because it still
requires me to ask them to modify their `.vimrc`, but I
suspect that there's no way to do this without changing
anything on their system. Additionally, if I have any
files in the directory that aren't notes, vim will still
highlight them with the `.custom_syntax.vim` file because
I don't know what the filetype is.

Is there any better way to accomlish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the old `mysyntaxfile` variable, I'd just `:syntax enable` (once) and then `:source` the syntax file. You can define an `:autocmd` that looks for an eponymous Vimscript file next to the original:

```
" Automatically source an eponymous <file>.vim or <file>.<ext>.vim if it exists, as a bulked-up
" modeline and to provide file-specific customizations.
function! s:AutoSource()
    let l:testedScripts = [expand('<afile>') . '.vim']
    if expand('<afile>:e') !=# 'vim'
        " Don't source the edited Vimscript file itself.
        call add(l:testedScripts, expand('<afile>:r') . '.vim')
    endif

    for l:filespec in l:testedScripts
        if filereadable(l:filespec)
            execute 'source' fnameescape(l:filespec)
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
augroup AutoSource
    autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead * call <SID>AutoSource()
augroup END
```

You do need this or something like this in your Vim configuration, though.